# Minimizing $x + \exp(-x) a$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let's fix $a \in \mathbb R$ and $f(x) := x + \exp(-x)a$. I want to find $\hat x = \textrm{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb R}f(x)$.

In order to do that, I wanted to calculate derivative of $f$:

$$f'(x) = 1 - xe^{-x}a$$

$$f'(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow xe^{-x} = \frac 1 a$$

And here there is a problem, because I don't see any closed form solution for this problem. Taking logarithm of both sides does not help:

$$-x\ln x = -\ln a$$

Still no closed form solution for $x$. Could you please give me a hand in finding $\hat x$?

Comment: There is no closed form for this. Look up Lambert W function.

Comment: I believe, $f'(x)=1-a\exp(-x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you remember what is $h'(x)$ if $h(x) = e^{f(x)}$?

$(e^{f(x)})' = f'(x)e^{f(x)}$

So if $g(x) = x + ae^{-x}$, then $g'(x) = x' + a(e^{h(x)})'$.

And if $h(x) = -x$ then $h'(x) = -1$.

So $g'(x) = 1 - ae^{-x}$.